# How to change the default browser for save to web preview in Photoshop CS6

Tags: photoshop

Hopefully this is the right place to ask, I have searched everywhere for the answer and though it seems like a simple thing I can't find an answer.

How do I change the default browser in save to web preview in Photoshop CS6 so it previews images in Chrome instead of Internet Explorer.  Or is there a good reason why it shouldn't be changed and I just haven't got to that bit in my Photoshop learning yet?

Comment: More like [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or even [**Graphic Design**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already doing, go to *File > Save for Web*.

When the dialog comes up, click the dropdown next to <kbd>Preview</kbd>, and choose *Edit List...*:

[image]

Click <kbd>Find All</kbd>, then select the appropriate browser and choose <kbd>Set As Default</kbd>:

[image]

The next time you click <kbd>Preview</kbd>, the image will open in your chosen browser.

Comment: @tatty27 That's actually where I looked first to begin with, too.

Answer (score -1):

Save the image you've created with photoshop, then rightclick on it->Open with...-> select Chrome as standard program. This might work.